# Не работает Toast java

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Toast t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void onClick (View v)
    {
        t =  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        if (t == null) {
            t.show();

        }
        else

        {   t.cancel();}



    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (t == null) {
        t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    } else {
        t.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: Работает только один раз и (больше никогда не работает )

Comment: @duna а смысл отменять тоаст? если и так стоит параметр `LENGTH_SHORT`

Comment: чтобы по сто раз не нажимали и оно потом долго не отображалось из памяти

Comment: @duna ну, лан. Занули t после cancel тогда, чтобы он опять в условие вписывался.

Comment: @iFr0z, Так будет работать через раз. Но ТС не задавал в вопросе никаких условий как оно **должно** работать, поэтому гадать не будем - пусть описывает задачу так чтобы можно было дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, вы неверно понимаете суть проверки на null. Метод *makeText* возвращает вам объект тоста, т.е. поле *t* уже не может быть пустым (вы только что его наполнили). Метод *show* отвечает только за показ тоста пользователю. Достоверно узнать, виден ли тост пользователю, невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Условие `if (t == null)  { t.show(); }` говорит о том, что тост нужно показывать только тогда, когда тост отсутствует. Т.е. никогда. Что и происходит.